# How to trigger an alert after separate click events

Tags: javascript

I have a form with 4 input boxes. I want to trigger an alert only after any 2 of the boxes have been clicked on. What is the easiest way to accomplish this (using only Javascript, not jQuery)?

HTML

```
<input id="FieldOne">Field One</><br>
<input id="FieldTwo">Field Two</><br>
<input id="FieldThree">Field Three</><br>
<input id="FieldThree">Field Four
```

Comment: Bind an event handler to each of the elements. The handler increases a counter. If the value is `>= 2`, show the alert.

Comment: Please show us your full code, what you tried, where is the problem... Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Just add an `addEventListener` to your input fields to fire a function every time they are being clicked.

```
<script>
  const counter = 0;
  const fieldOne = document.getElementById('FieldOne').addEventListener("click", countUp);
  const fieldTwo = document.getElementById('FieldTwo').addEventListener("click", countUp);
  const fieldThree = document.getElementById('FieldThree').addEventListener("click", countUp);
  const fieldFour = document.getElementById('FieldFour').addEventListener("click", countUp);

  function countUp() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    if (counter === 2) {
      alert('You have clicked two inputs!');
    }
  }
</script>
```